# JSONSerialization in Swift 3 error with unicode characters

Tags: json, swift, swift3

I am trying to parse a JSON Object similar to this:

`{"topics":[{"tid":24909,"uid":400,"cid":"3","mainPid":790889,"title":"Retrasados just being retrasados una vez mOptional("\u{00E1}")s en Galicia","slug":"24909/retrasados-just-being-retrasados-una-vez-mOptional("\u{00E1}")s-en-galicia","timestamp":1473334344094,"lastposttime":1473414364688,"postcount":23,"viewcount":95,"locked":false,"deleted":false,"pinned":false,"teaserPid":"791474","titleRaw":"Retrasados just being retrasados una vez mOptional("\u{00E1}")s en Galicia"}]}`

Using this Swift 3 code:

```

```
do{ 

       let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: cleanData.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, options: .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

        nextStart = (json!["nextStart"] as? Int)!
        let topics = json!["topics"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]

        for t in topics!{
            //print(t["tid"])
            let topic = Thread(threadDic: t)
            //print(topic.title)
            self.topics.append(topic)
        }

        // Main UI Thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.indicator.stopAnimating()
        })

    }catch{
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    }
```

```

But it gives me the following error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 122." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 122.}

I used this code with Swift 2.2, but now it doesnt work.. I think the error comes with the unicode special chars, like ¿,ñ.. 
As you can see, the all are Optional("\u{...}").

Anyone know how to fix it?? I am new in Swift.

Comment: If there's stuff like `vez mOptional("\u{00E1}")s en Galicia` *in your JSON* then your JSON is malformed and you can't do anything with the decoding part. Fix your JSON first. Or maybe you didn't explain your issue properly? Please add details, thanks.

Comment: @EricAya my JSON comes from the server over a WebSocket message. I am using this library: https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket. Maybe the problem is in the library??

Comment: Sure it could, you probably used an optional string as a string without unwrapping it first.